# React js Controlled Form Alt js Flux Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, redux, flux

i have this

### loginpage.js

```
<TextField value="this.state.boomba" name="boomba" onChange={loginaction.handleInputChange} />
```

### loginaction.js

```
    constructor() {
        this.generateActions(
    'handleInputChangeSuccess'
    );
    }
    handleInputChange(e){
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

   //here the name and value are perfect. 

        this.handleInputChangeSuccess(name,value);
    }
```

### loginstore.js

```
  constructor() {
    this.bindActions(LoginActions);

    this.boomba = '';

    }
  handleInputChangeSuccess(name,val){
    this.setState({
      [name] : val
    });
    console.log(val); // this line prints LoginActions.handleInputChangeSuccess
  }
```

Whenever im writing in the textfield. it dissapears... it means the this.boomba is always null. so it ovverides what i write.

im using alt js library alt.js.org/ . i dont think its a problem in library. but its in my code.

Comment: onChange={loginaction.handleInputChange} should be onChange={this.handleInputChange}

Comment: @Ved but handleInputChange is in `loginaction class` not `loginpage class`